# PostgreSQL: Optimizing bulk INSERT INTO/SELECT FROM

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, bulkinsert

In my Postgresql schema I have a `jobs` table and an `accounts` table. Once a day I need to schedule a job for each account by inserting a row per account into the `jobs` table. This can done using a simple `INSERT INTO.. SELECT FROM` statement, but is there any empirical way I can know if I am straining my DB by this bulk insert and whether I should chunk the inserts instead?

Postgres often does miraculous work so I have no idea if bulk inserting 500k records at a time is better than 100 x 5k, for example. The bulk insert works today but can take minutes to complete.

One additional data point: the jobs table has a uniqueness constraint on account ID, so this statement includes an `ON CONFLICT` clause too.

Comment: Could your share the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this insert statement? (Be aware that the insert will be executed!)

Comment: I hope this is what you're after: https://gist.github.com/rarkins/cc64ef6d61f6d807f8bfdaebfbbe67aa. It is a smaller scale insert done hourly with up to 50k rows. In this case most of them were already in the table so most conflicted and did nothing

Comment: A transaction inserting 1 million rows is no more "expensive" than a transaction inserting 1000 rows.

Comment: This is a query plan, but not the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) . There are no timings, no-one can see where most of the time is spend and what could be optimised.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, it doesn't matter how many rows you modify in a single transaction, so it is preferable to do everything in a single statement so that you don't end up with half the work done in case of a failure. The only consideration is that transactions should not take too long, but if that happens once a day, it is no problem.